# K-9 Mail - Pushing mail only when interacting with app needed

Tags: email, tablet, push-notifications, imap, k9-mail

With K-9 Mail, could you please advise if it is possible to have these mail fetching settings:

1) Polling every hour, both when interacting with the app and when running in the background.

but also:

2) Pushing all folders only when interacting with the app, but not when the app is just running in the background.

The reason for this is that I like push to update folders promptly when interacting with the app, but don't want to have unnecessary push connections open in the background.  However, I still like to poll in the background to be notified of new messages periodically.

I am using a Gmail IMAP account on a tablet running Android 5.0.1.

I have read through the documentation and been through the settings but would just like clarification on the above points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not.

It is not possible to configure the push service to only run while the app is open.